# WebScraping with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to do WebScraping on the Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung Archiv. I need to click on the button 'erweiterte suche' but I keep getting the below error

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="g_00271e6200ad4985a0a9c8f9b0032c42"]"}.

I have my code here:

```
import os
import requests
import openpyxl
import smtplib
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver.get("https://fazarchiv.faz.net")

search_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="searchForm"]/div[1]/input""")
search_elem.click()
search_elem.send_keys('Bürokratie')

erweiterte_suche = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="g_00271e6200ad4985a0a9c8f9b0032c42"]""")
erweiterte_suche.click()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest not using selenium altogether because it's not being updated anymore. It's too obsolete

Comment: @AnonumousPomp What do you mean? Selenium is de-facto standard of autonomous interaction.

Comment: oops I was thinking of phantomjs. sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you want to click "Suche" button. The gray one.

So you can search the word "Bürokratie".

Your code also have missing parts.
Like driver setting.

This code work for me, you can use:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    driver.get("https://fazarchiv.faz.net")

    search_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="searchForm"]/div[1]/input""")
    search_elem.click()
    search_elem.send_keys('Bürokratie')

    erweiterte_suche = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("""#searchForm > div.boxRow.clearfix > input""")
    erweiterte_suche.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The id is dynamic and changes every time the site is loaded. Use class instead

```
erweiterte_suche = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="boxExtendedSearch ext-hidden globalArrowRedRight"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
erweiterte_suche = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='clearfix']/a[1]")
```

or this:

```py
erweiterte_suche = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='erweiterte Suche']")
```